# graphviz dot ignores 'rank' constraints

Tags: dot

I constructed a simple graph:

```
digraph{
    rankdir = LR;
    { 
        rank="source";
        Sa;
        Sb;
        Sc;
        St;
    }

    St -> {t_1[label="t",shape=plaintext];}

    Na;
    {t_a[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Na
    Sa->Na;
    Sb->Na;
    Sc->Na;

    subgraph cluster_b { 
        fillcolor = "#ddDDdd";
        style=filled;
        label="";
        Nb1;
        Nb;
        Nb1->Nb;
    }
    {t_2[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Nb1
    Sa->Nb;

    Nc;
    {t_c[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Nc

    Nd;
    {t_d[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Nd


    Na->Nd;
    Nb->Nc;
    Nd->O1;
    Nc->Nd;

    { 
        rank="sink";
        O1;
    }
}
```

[view online here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rankdir%20%3D%20LR%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank%3D%22source%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Sa%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Sb%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Sc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20St%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20St%20-%3E%20%7Bt_1%5Blabel%3D%22t%22%2Cshape%3Dplaintext%5D%3B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Na%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bt_a%5Blabel%3D%22t%22%2Cshape%3Dplaintext%5D%3B%7D-%3ENa%0A%20%20%20%20Sa-%3ENa%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Sb-%3ENa%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Sc-%3ENa%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_b%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fillcolor%20%3D%20%22%23ddDDdd%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3D%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Nb1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Nb%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Nb1-%3ENb%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bt_2%5Blabel%3D%22t%22%2Cshape%3Dplaintext%5D%3B%7D-%3ENb1%0A%20%20%20%20Sa-%3ENb%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Nc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bt_c%5Blabel%3D%22t%22%2Cshape%3Dplaintext%5D%3B%7D-%3ENc%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Nd%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bt_d%5Blabel%3D%22t%22%2Cshape%3Dplaintext%5D%3B%7D-%3ENd%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Na-%3ENd%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Nb-%3ENc%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Nd-%3EO1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Nc-%3ENd%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rank%3D%22sink%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20O1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

It seems that dot is ignoring the `rank="source"`.
According to the documentation

> If rank="min", all nodes are placed on the minimum rank. If
>   rank="source", all nodes are placed on the minimum rank, and the only
>   nodes on the minimum rank belong to some subgraph whose rank attribute
>   is "source" or "min".

The `Sx` nodes should be the only ones on the lowest ranks.
(as if there would be an additional `St->t_2[style=invis];`  edge).

Is this a bug? do i misunderstand the documentation?

Comment: When using http://www.webgraphviz.com/I get a slightly different picture, is this what you are looking for? Maybe it is version problem.

Comment: The differences that i see on that site are negligible. but the main problem is the same. nothing other than `source` ranked nodes should be at the lowest rank

Answer (score 1):

I vote "bug" (probably in software, maybe in documentation).
Here is a work-around, using the **minlen** attribute to "force" the *Nb* node (and the cluster) "down" the ranks.

```
digraph{
    rankdir = LR;
    { 
        rank="source";
        Sa;
        Sb;
        Sc;
        St;
    }
    
    St -> {t_1[label="t",shape=plaintext];}
    
    Na;
    {t_a[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Na
    Sa->Na;
    Sb->Na;
    Sc->Na;
    
    subgraph cluster_b { 
        fillcolor = "#ddDDdd";
        style=filled;
        label="";
        Nb1;
        Nb;
        Nb1->Nb;
    }
    {t_2[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Nb1
    Sa->Nb [minlen=3]  // will this move the cluster??
    
    Nc;
    {t_c[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Nc
    
    Nd;
    {t_d[label="t",shape=plaintext];}->Nd

    
    Na->Nd;
    Nb->Nc;
    Nd->O1;
    Nc->Nd;
    
    { 
        rank="sink";
        O1;
    }
}
```

Giving:
[image]